# Delete parts of filename

Tags: applescript, rename

I would like to change ugly file names (as a byproduct of my bad programming) like "Booklet xxx.pdf kopie.pdf" to "xxx.pdf". Automator changes it to> " xxx.pdf" (with the very annoying space in front of the file name...

This is what I can come up with…

```
    tell application "Finder"
    set allFiles to selection
    search of (name of every item of allFiles) for "Booklet "
try
    if file exists then delete "Booklet " of name
end try
    search of (name of every item of allFiles) for ".pdf kopie"
try
    if file exists then delete ".pdf kopie" of name
end try
    end tell
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rename a file by setting the `name` property:

```
activate application "SystemUIServer" -- http://www.openradar.me/9406282
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    repeat with f in (get selection)
        if name of f ends with "kopie.pdf" then
            set name of f to text 9 thru -11 of (get name of f)
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Or run something like this in a shell:

```
cd directory; for f in *kopie.pdf; do f2=${f% *}; mv "$f" "${f2##* }"; done
```

`${f% *}` removes the shortest `​ *` pattern from the end of `f` and `${f2##* }` removes the longest `* ​` pattern from the start of `f2`.

Comment: Thanks for helping this noob! It worked :-) Had some trouble figuring out what text 9 thru -11 meant but now I understand (characters)...